# Binding click event to td vs table

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I want to build excel like utility in HTML. Suppose I've table[id "myTbl"] with 20 rows & 20 columns. I would like to add textbox inside td whenever users clicks on it with td text as its value.

Suppose my table is 
 [image]

I've 2 options to achieve this [both are working fine]

Option I

```
$("#myTbl").bind("click",function(e){
    var obj = e.target;
    if(obj.nodeName == "TD"){
        $(obj).html("<input type='text' value='"+$(obj).html()+"'></input>");
    }
});
```

Option II

```
$("#myTbl tr td").bind("click",function(e){
    if($("input",$(this)).length==0){
        $(this).html("<input type='text' value='"+$(this).html()+"'></input>");
    }
});
```

My question is which option is better in terms of performance.

Comment: Why not having hidden textbox in all cells in advance then show/hide it upon click and blur?

Comment: But that will increase my page size. Also not necessary that user will click on each td. Right?

Comment: that's right but you asked about performance.. with modern bandwidth having few extra kilobytes won't have any visible effect on page load time. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first of your two options will create only one event handler, so it'll be more performant.
Obtaining the target via the event as you do has negligible cost.

To do it the 'jQuery' way, you might want to use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
$("#myTbl").delegate("td", "click", function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.html("<input type='text' value='"+$this.text()+"'></input>");
});
```

Comment: beat me to the punch.  it should probably be noted that the delegate method was added in 1.4.2, so you'll need to be using the latest stuff.

Comment: Does that code do the same thing as creating event handlers for each `td`? Also, why is it the 'jQuery' way?

Comment: No it creates only one event handler. It is the 'jQuery way' because this is a jQuery function that was intended for exactly this purpose; it handles the event target logic etc. for you (the context of the handler function is the `td` element).

Comment: It says in the docs that it's equivalent to this `$("table").each(function(){ $("td", this).live("hover", function(){ $(this).toggleClass("hover"); }); });` which (sorry for the mashed up code) if I'm not mistaken, grabs all tds within the current table and adds a live hover event to each one.

Comment: It's equivalent in effect, but much more efficient. It uses event bubbling in a single event handler. I only know because I asked the same question of Nick Craver ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would say that binding it to the table is much better because you don't have the extra overhead of maintaining all the click handlers for each cell.