# Change jQuery cell table values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a question about javascript and jQuery. I'm new about this.
I use jQuery tablesort. I would to know how can I change the value of one cell.

Probably I have to use something as this:

```
$(function() { 

  $("table").tablesorter({ sortList: [[3,1],[0,0]] }); 

  $("table tbody td.discount").click(function() { 

    // randomize a number 
    var resort = "", // resort variable set to anything BUT false (without quotes) will trigger the automatic resort 
      discount = '$' + Math.round(Math.random() * Math.random() * 100) + '.' + ('0' + Math.round(Math.random() * Math.random() * 100)).slice(-2); 
    $(this).text(discount); 

    // set resort flag to false to prevent automatic resort 
    // leave the resort flag as undefined, or with any other value, to automatically resort the table 
    $("table").trigger("updateCell",[this, resort]); 

    return false; 
  }); 

});
```

in this example I can change the cell's value when I click on it.
I would to change the cell value into one my javascript function.
How can I make this?

Comment: Can you state your question more clearly? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332751/binding-click-event-to-td-vs-table

Comment: I would to change the cell value from a my javascript function. Probably I have to use something as this: $("table").trigger("updateCell",[this, resort]);  but in this code 'this' is the cell that I have clicked. Right? I would to change a generic cell value. For example: We can suppose that we have a javascript function as this: changeValueCell(numberLine, numberColum). How can I to implement this function?

Answer (score -1):

**HTML**

```
 <table id="myTbl">
    <tr>
        <td>Joe</td>
        <td>White</td>
        <td>25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Joe1</td>
        <td>White1</td>
        <td>2522</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    $("#myTbl").delegate("td", "click", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        console.log($this);
        $this.html("New Value");
    });
});
```